# Visual Studio 2013 compiler bug with operator star (operator*)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I get an MSVC 2013 internal compiler error (`error C1001`) trying to compile a C++ class that has `operator*()` member template that can be optionally disabled via substitution failure.

Below is the minimal code that gives this error. Note that I also defined a template method `get()` that does exactly the same thing as `operator*()` but compiles just fine.

Is this a legit MSVC bug or is there something wrong with this code? It compiles fine with gcc ([link](https://ideone.com/9MXX6F)).

Does anyone know how to fix it or work around it?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Readonly
{
  typedef void read;
};

struct ReadWrite
{
  typedef void read;
  typedef void write;
};

template <typename AccessLevel>
class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper(double value)
    : _value(value)
  {}

  template <typename A = AccessLevel, typename = typename A::read>
  const double& operator*() const
  {
    return _value;
  }

  template <typename A = AccessLevel, typename = typename A::write>
  double& operator*()
  {
    return _value;
  }

  template <typename A = AccessLevel, typename = typename A::read>
  const double& get() const
  {
    return _value;
  }

  template <typename A = AccessLevel, typename = typename A::write>
  double& get()
  {
    return _value;
  }

protected:
  double _value;
};

int main()
{
  Wrapper<ReadWrite> wr(88);
  Wrapper<Readonly> const_wr(99);

  //// uncomment this to get error C1001
  //std::cout << "*wr = " << *wr << std::endl;
  //std::cout << "*const_wr = " << *const_wr << std::endl;

  std::cout << "wr.get() = " << wr.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "const_wr.get() = " << const_wr.get() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Internal Compiler Error is always a *compiler bug*.

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Not always. Doing infinite recursion with template meta-programming is the programmers fault. I know because it happened to... a friend of mine :)

Comment: I have used vs2015 to compile the code.And result is success.So i doubt the compiler more than the code.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Agreed, :-) but I should think compilers will do well to put upper bounds in their *implementation-defined* limits, in order to give tangible errors. [GCC usually does that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c360a2a3505c11). Ditto clang

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Of course, but it's still a fatal compiler error :P

Comment: @StoryTeller at least they gave reasonable diagnostics. Surprisingly, recent versions of ICC and MSVC still go nuts... https://godbolt.org/g/VKpQMM ... Well, its their freedom, since ISO-C++ imposes no constraint on them... But, I think they could do better... Permit me to talk like ignorant managers would say: *"They should just add a **simple** if-else statement to cater for that."* ... :-)

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Not ignorant enough. It should also *"rely on big data and neural networks. And be green"*

Comment: @WhiZTiM http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d676d04dba45f9 So far this example crashes any compiler I know of with an ICE. Not that it's a useful test case...

Comment: [Compiles with VC2017](http://rextester.com/ZQNM94416), for what it's worth. VC2013 is kind of ancient, there's little hope it will see any fixes.